# Command Line Interface- Development

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-tool

I am trying to build a CLI for my application.

Currently, we have a jenkins plugin that wraps our functionality and it is written in java. I would like to create a CLI for our applicaiton.

Can someone suggest me a good place to start with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Remember that we don't know who you are, what you're working on and can't see your screen. For example you have tagged "dockerfile" but your question does not mention docker at all. What should we think about that?

Answer (score 0):

Java curses sounds promising: https://github.com/kba/jcurses, since i dont know your specific needs, i cant suggest more